# Using Blade files as Widgets in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a situation in which a user has a homepage which will be full of widgets they can add or remove by clicking on them.

Each widget is essentially just a blade file stored under `resources/views/widgets`

**An example:**

```
@php 
$widgetNo = 15; 
$exist = false;
@endphp 

 @hasanyrole('News Contributor|News Approver')
<div class="grid-item element-item">
    <section class="widget" id="articles-cms">

        <div class="form-box widget light_blue">

            <div class="row header">

                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h2>News articles</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2 AddWidget">
                    @if(Route::current()->uri() == 'welcome')

                    <i class="fa fa-bars "></i>

                    @elseif(Route::current()->uri() == 'widget-library')


                    <form action="{{action('WidgetController@store')}}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="widgets" value="12">


                        <button type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus "></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>

                    @else @endif
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                    <p class="info">Create and edit News and updates</p>
                    <a href="/editable/news-and-updates" class="btn btn-filled-navy btn-full-width no-margin">Click Here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
@endrole
```

The reason for the PHP at the beginning is so that each widget has an ID I can work with, as you can see each widget also has a store and destroy form based on where they are within the application.

Structurally I have two tables: `users` and `widgets`

The `widgets` table looks like this:

[image]

In my User Model I have a one to many relation to Widgets that looks like this:

```
/**
 * A user may have many Widgets
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function widgets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Widget::class, 'user_id', 'id')->orderBy('position', 'asc');
}
```

With this in place I can utilize the relation in the view.

I also have these two methods in the Widget model.

```
/**
* Get the user that has this Widget
*/
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Check whether a given user has this Widget
 */
public function getIsSelected()
{
    $selected = $this->user()->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)->first();

    return (!is_null($selected)) ? true : false;
}
```

This is so I can check whether a Widget has been selected by a user.

At the moment, in my homepage I just have a switch statement.

```
@foreach ($user->widgets as $widget) 

    @switch($widget->widget_id) 

        @case (1) 
            @include('widgets.quick-search-full-width') 
            @break; 
        @case(2) 
            @include('widgets.calendar') 
            @break; 
        @case (3) 
            @include('widgets.suggestion') 
            @break; 
        @case (4) 
            @include('widgets.task')
            @break; 
        @case (5) 
            @include('widgets.quick-search') 
            @break; 
        @case (6) 
            @include('widgets.message')
            @break; 
        @case(7) 
            @include('widgets.find-expert') 
            @break; 
        @case (8) 
            @include('widgets.holiday') 
            @break; 
        @case (9) 
            @include('widgets.expenses')
            @break; 
        @case (10) 
            @include('widgets.snap-pole') 
            @break; 
        @case (11) 
            @include('widgets.teams-cms') 
            @break; 
        @case (12)
            @include('widgets.events-cms') 
            @break; 
        @case (13) 
            @include('widgets.team-cms') 
            @break;  
        @case (14) 
            @include('widgets.article-todo') 
            @break; 
        @case (15) 
            @include('widgets.article-cms') 
            @break; 
        @case (16) 
            @include('widgets.vacancies') 
            @break;
        @case(17) 
            @include('widgets.yammer') 
            @break; 
        @default
        <h3>You currently have no widgets</h3>
    @endswitch 

@endforeach
```

My question is, is there a better way to pull in or use these widgets as obviously at the moment, displaying of Widgets is entirely dependant on having an ID within the widget using vanilla PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you can have blade_name field in database so in that form for example you have 'calendar' in the record of that widget.
so you can add your widgets like this

```
@foreach ($user->widgets as $widget) 
@include('widgets.'.$widget->blade_name)
@endforeach
```

Comment: With this approach would you go with an individual Widgets table or just add the blade name as an extra field?

Comment: as an extra field in the widget table beside other fields

Comment: How would one programmatically add the name of the blade?

Comment: now I got your question I guess, you should have a table which has widgets with field blade name , where does your widget_id refer to ? is it just something for hardCode?

Comment: I hardcoded the Widget ID into each HTML block, however this approach seems a bit flakey

Comment: yep , have a separate table for widgets

Comment: My only question from this would be, how would you manage the creation of new widgets?

Comment: the base widget table I think you should insert manually because it's related to the name of the new blade you are making
but users can have a page to select which widgets to have and add that widget_id to their table

Comment: Also if you are not wanting to make tables for widgets, you can add a static array as well, like $widgets = ['quick-search','calender','suggestion'...]
And use them like
@if(isset($widgets[$widget->widget_id])
@include($widgets[$widget->widget_id]);